# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.example

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am facing with this issue. Not able to understand how to resolve it. can you guys help me resolve this.

here is my code

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=BusinessType.class)
 @JoinColumn(name="typeid" , insertable = false,updatable = false)
 public Set<BusinessType> getBusinessType1() {
  return businessType1;
 }

 public void setBusinessType1(Set<BusinessType> businessType1) {
  this.businessType1 = businessType1;
 }
```

my error log:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.saveDollar.model.DealPosted.businessType1
```

thanks for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mappings makes no sense. It's a ManyToOne association, so it is supposed to reference *one* entity. But its type is `Set<BusinessType>`. If a DealPosted has *one* BusinessType, then the methods should be

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "typeid", insertable = false,updatable = false)
public BusinessType getBusinessType1() {
    return businessType1;
}

public void setBusinessType1(BusinessType businessType1) {
    this.businessType1 = businessType1;
}
```

Comment: I tried that also. But when I am trying that one, I am getting only one record repeadtedly. I am getting this error                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)

Comment: @One: "this error": which error? What you posted is a line of a stack trace that has nothing to do with Hibernate, and everything to do with Jackson serialization.

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPrope‌​rtyWriter.java:569)

Comment: I'll repeat. That is not an error. It's a random line of a big exception stack trace. And it's unrelated to this problem. So, ask *another* question, explaining what you're doing, and containing the *complete* stack trace of the exception.

Comment: yeah thanks my issue got fixed. Actually what I done is, I have given OneToMany relation in the parent class and ManyToOne relation in child class.So when I select the child class its mapping reversed.Thats how I got the error. So this issue solved by removing OneToMany relation in parent class and also removed Set<BusinessType> changed it to BusinessType. anyways thanks for your answer